# @RequestParam and @PathVariable encapsulation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, request-mapping

Is there any way to encapsulate this two values into one object?

```
public ResponseEntity<TestResponse> test(@PathVariable("customerId") String customerId,
        @RequestParam(name = "reason", required = true) String reason,
        @RequestParam(name = "attribute", required = true) List<String> attributes) {
```

I think that I should be able to do it with this way:

```
public ResponseEntity<TestResponse> test(@MaybeSomeMagicAnnotation? Request request) {
```

where Request class has those three properties (customerId, reason, attributes).

I'm using spring boot 1.5.9

Comment: you don't need anything. just create the Request class which has these three fields and use that as the method argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by defining an object that matches the request parameters, etc.

Example (untested):

```
public class MyRequest {
   @NotNull
   private String customerId;

   @NotNull
   private String reason;

   @NotNull
   @NotEmpty
   private List<String> attributes;

   // getters and setters left out for brevity.
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<TestResponse> test(@Valid MyRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What about required param Andrzej custom name on attributes (collection od attribute gives attribute)?

Comment: @pustypawel Added annotations to show how to do that.

Comment: That case was clear for me. Whats with attribute name (on URL i want to have "attribute" in class collection "attributes"

Comment: Another question - is that any way to make this object immutable?(when i'm trying to do it i'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: packages.Request.<init>()

Comment: Ok. I checked spring source code - there is no simple way to do that. I have been chosen first solution and I'm just creating manually my complex object in controller. Thanks